# Trying to find average throws for a dice game

Tags: java, loops, dice

I am trying to simulate a dice game experiment. The goal is to find the average amount of rolls it will take to get the same value of a die to show in the wanted amount of consecutive rolls.

My program asks the user how many times the user wants to run the program. So it will run the loop, then stop after they get their answer, then show the amount of throws it took. Then it will repeat as many times as the user specified.

I want to take the `totalThrows` from each experiment and add each `totalThrows` together then divide by my variable `turns` to get the average amount of throws it would take.

I am having some trouble getting the sum of all the `totalThrows`. And I can only get the last `totalThrow`. I would appreciate it if any of you could give some suggestions on how to resolve this. I think an array could help but I haven't learned arrays in class yet.

Here is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// WRITE main's CODE HERE 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random randomNumber = new Random();

    int value, turns=0, nSides, rollLength; //declare variables
    int totalThrows=0, roll=0, count=0,finish=0;

    //ask for input
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of sides (2, 4, or 6): ");
        nSides = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the value sought. Must be in the range [1," + nSides + "]: ");
        value = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the length of the run.\n" + "Remember, the bigger it is the longer it will take to find it");
        rollLength = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter number of times to run the experiment:"); 
        turns = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\n");

    do
    {   
        //Countinue loop until count = rollLength
        while(count!=rollLength){  
            roll = randomNumber.nextInt(nSides)+1;  
            totalThrows++;        //will increment after every roll

            //When roll comes up as a watched value I want to increment count by one
            if(roll==value){  
            count++;    //This should stop until count is my rollLength
            }
            else if (roll!=value){  //When an unwanted roll comes up start over
            count=0;
            }
        }
        //finish counts how many times the experiment was successful
        if (count==rollLength){
            finish++;             
        }
           System.out.println("\n"); 

           //Display totalThrows it took until rollLength variable occurs
           System.out.println("Your total rolls is: "+ totalThrows);  
    } while(finish!=turns);  //This will repeat the experiment
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply declare another variable up top:

```
int averageThrows = 0;
```

Add to this value each time the loop ends:

```
do {
    // ...
    averageThrows += totalThrows;
} while( finish != turns );
```

And then divide it by the number of turns:

```
averageThrows /= turns;
```

That ought to do it for you.